# T-SQL Grouping result-set based on multiple Dates and Times

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, time, grouping

```
ID....| Date Created on System |.Action..............| Appointment Date
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID123 |......15/03/2013 16:32..| Due.......          |.NULL
ID123 |......05/04/2013 09:27..|.Appointment booked..|.08/04/2013 11:30
ID123 |......24/03/2014 11:55..|.Appointment booked..|.10/04/2014 09:30
ID123 |......09/02/2014 11:43..|.Appointment Due.....|.NULL
ID123 |......24/03/2014 11:55..|.Appointment booked..|.20/06/2014 09:30
```

I need to separate the above result-set every time 'appointment Due' appears with the succeeding Appointments booked actions linked however I also need to filter the Appointments Booked by the created date giving me the Appointment Due date and the earliest Appointment Booked date with in the group

i.e

```
ID....| Date Created on System |.Action............| Appointment Date
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID123 |.15/03/2013 16:32.......|.Appointment Due...|...NULL


ID123 |.05/04/2013 09:27.......|.Appointment booked.|.08/04/2013 11:30
```

The final resulting set should be two rows as follows

```
ID    | Date Created on System 1 | Action 1        | Date Created on System | Action 2          | Appointment Date|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID123 | 15/03/2013 16:32         | Appointment Due | 05/04/2013 09:27       | Appointment booked | 08/04/2013 11:30
ID123 | 09/02/2014 11:43         | Appointment Due | 24/03/2014 11:55       | Appointment booked | 20/06/2014 09:30
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a primary key on your table? i.e. an ID that auto increments? 1,2,3,4,5 or something else?

Comment: yes there is a ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, set on the resultset

Comment: Is the ID column in your example above which displays ID123 in each row, showing that all of these rows are related to a particular person ?

Comment: yes the id is a person unique identifier and each unique identifier i.e the ID123 (which is just and example) has multiple rows as above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a sqlFiddle for you demonstrating this. I have added an ID column and PersonId column as per your comments: [see here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c2282/10/0)

Hope this works for you!